# android camera capture image size

Tags: android, android-camera, android-capture

i am capturing image using below code it's working fine but problem is that when capture image using default camera app it capture image 2048*1546px image and size is aprox 780 to 800kb and while capturing using below code it capture image 640*480 and size is 70-80kb. so i want to capture full size image.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "CamActivity";
private Preview preview;
private Camera camera;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preview = new Preview(this, (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
    preview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);
    preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    });
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick)).setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
                    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // preview.camera = Camera.open();
    camera = Camera.open();
    camera.startPreview();
    preview.setCamera(camera);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        preview.setCamera(null);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}

private void resetCam() {
    camera.startPreview();
    preview.setCamera(camera);
}

ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        // Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
    }
};

PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
};

PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String temp = "" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-"
                + StaticData.pad(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
                + StaticData.pad(c.get(Calendar.DATE)) + "-"
                + StaticData.pad(c.get(Calendar.HOUR)) + "-"
                + StaticData.pad(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + "-"
                + StaticData.pad(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + HomeScreenActivity.MyDir);
        String backupDBPath = "Image" + "_" + temp + ".jpg";
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            File backupDB = new File(dir, backupDBPath);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(backupDB);
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            AppLog.logString(TAG + "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            resetCam();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
    }
};
}
```

Preview.java

```
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private final String TAG = "Prev: ";
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Size mPreviewSize;
private List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
private Camera mCamera;

Preview(Context context, SurfaceView sv) {
    super(context);
    mSurfaceView = sv;
    mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    mCamera = camera;
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        requestLayout();
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
    // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
    // of stretching it.
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    AppLog.logString(TAG+"1width : "+width);
    AppLog.logString(TAG+"1height: "+height);

    if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"!=width : "+width);
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"!=height: "+height);
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
        final View child = getChildAt(0);

        final int width = r - l;
        final int height = b - t;

        int previewWidth = width;
        int previewHeight = height;

        AppLog.logString(TAG+"2width : "+width);
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"2height: "+height);

        if (mPreviewSize != null) {
            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
        }

        // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
        if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
            final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
            child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0, (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2,height);
        } else {
            final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
            child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2, width,(height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
        }

        AppLog.logString(TAG+"3width : "+previewWidth);
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"3height: "+previewHeight);
    }
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to draw.
    try {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        AppLog.errorLog(TAG + "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }
}

private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            }
            else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;
                if (newArea > resultArea) {
                    result = size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (result);
}

private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
    if (sizes == null)
        return null;
    Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    int targetHeight = h;

    // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
    for (Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "width  :" + mPreviewSize.width);
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "height :" + mPreviewSize.height);
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "w  :" + w);
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "h  :" + h);

        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width,mPreviewSize.height);
        requestLayout();
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setZoomChangeListener(new OnZoomChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onZoomChange(int zoomValue, boolean stopped, Camera camera) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
 }
}
```